# MySQL Could not create connection to database server

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to connect to my mySQL server from my android app. Don't mind how unsafe it is, it's not meant to be published. I am not able to make a connection to my mysql server (version 5.7). lireBdd method is called in my MainActivity

```
public class ConnexionBdd {
public ListeID lireBdd() { //retourne une liste contenant tous les id de la bdd
    IdEnvoyes listebdd = new IdEnvoyes();
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://193.xxx.xxx.250:3306/freecovid";
        String user = "root";
        String passwd = "root";

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, passwd);

        //Création d'un objet Statement
        Statement state = conn.createStatement();
        //L'objet ResultSet contient le résultat de la requête SQL
        ResultSet result = state.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM freecovid.idMalades");
        //On récupère les MetaData
        ResultSetMetaData resultMeta = result.getMetaData();

        while(result.next()){
            for(int i = 0; i <= resultMeta.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                listebdd.addId((Integer) result.getObject(i));
            }
        }

        result.close();
        state.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return listebdd;
}
```

I'm getting these errors :

```
  2020-06-26 16:14:54.491 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
2020-06-26 16:14:54.491 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.491 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.491 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:403)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.491 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.492 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.492 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.492 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.492 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:861)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.492 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2266)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.492 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2015)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.492 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:768)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.492 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.492 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.492 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.492 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:403)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.492 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:385)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.492 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:323)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.492 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:580)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.492 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:218)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.492 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at com.iutlan.freecovid.ConnexionBdd.lireBdd(ConnexionBdd.java:22)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.492 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at com.iutlan.freecovid.MainActivity.testbdd(MainActivity.java:69)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.492 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at com.iutlan.freecovid.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:56)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.492 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7894)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.492 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7881)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.492 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.492 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3279)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.492 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3443)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.492 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.492 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.492 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.492 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2040)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.492 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.492 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.492 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7520)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.492 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.492 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.492 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.493 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err: Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
2020-06-26 16:14:54.493 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1571)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.493 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:389)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.493 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.493 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.493 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.493 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.493 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:211)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.493 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:299)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.493 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2187)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.493 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2220)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.493 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:    ... 28 more
2020-06-26 16:14:54.497 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
2020-06-26 16:14:54.498 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.498 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.498 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:403)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.498 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.498 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.498 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.498 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.498 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:861)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.498 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2266)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.498 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2015)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.498 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:768)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.498 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.498 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.498 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.498 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:403)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.498 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:385)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.498 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:323)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.498 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:580)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.498 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:218)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.498 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at com.iutlan.freecovid.ConnexionBdd.lireBdd(ConnexionBdd.java:22)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.498 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at com.iutlan.freecovid.MainActivity.testbdd(MainActivity.java:70)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.498 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at com.iutlan.freecovid.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:56)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.498 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7894)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.498 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7881)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.498 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.498 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3279)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.498 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3443)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.498 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.498 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.498 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.498 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2040)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.498 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.498 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.498 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7520)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.498 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.498 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.498 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.499 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err: Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
2020-06-26 16:14:54.499 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1571)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.499 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:389)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.499 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.499 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.499 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.499 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.499 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:211)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.499 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:299)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.499 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2187)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.499 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2220)
2020-06-26 16:14:54.499 9384-9384/com.iutlan.freecovid W/System.err:    ... 28 more
```

I'm using MySQL Connector 5.1.49 since v8 wasn't working for me.

Comment: Could you please confirm what version of MySql are you using? There could be compatibility  issue of connector version and mysql version

Comment: This Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); //ERREUR ICI LORS DE TESTS  giving error indicates you don't have the library in the project. Try to use the class and make an import see if it finds the library.

Comment: I followed this tutorial : https://tecadmin.net/install-mysql-server-on-debian9-stretch/ and chose my sql 5.7

Comment: My comment isn't relevant anymore, i have imported :import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.Statement; which are all found

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace, as far as I can tell you are missing exception causes here. However, as I also mentioned on your other question, you really shouldn't use JDBC drivers from Android.

Comment: I have added the full stacktrace. I was supposed to work in a group for this school project unfortunately i am working alone and i don't have a lot of time. I am looking for the most simple and the quickest solution here

Comment: The problem is that Android doesn't allow network communication on the 'main' thread. See the duplicate for more information.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help, i'll check this out !